# What is the difference between these types of destructuring

Tags: javascript

I've seen this in a repository, but I'm not quite sure what is exactly happening. Is the var value replaced or is the child question of value taken from var data?

```
const { value: question } = data;
const { value } = data;
```

Comment: It's just renaming. `{ value: question } = data` takes the property `value` and assigns it to a local variable called `question`. The second one takes the property `value` and assigns it to a local variable called `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A property can be unpacked from an object and assigned to a variable with a different name than the object property.

```
var o = {p: 42, q: true};
var {p: foo, q: bar} = o;

console.log(foo); // 42 
console.log(bar); // true
```

Here, for example, var {p: foo} = o takes from the object o the property named p and assigns it to a local variable named foo.

[MDN - Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 2):

### Destructuring properties of an object

```
const { value } = data;
```

creates a block-scoped constant named `value`, and assigns to it `data.value`.

It's **identical** to

```
const value = data.value;
```

---

### Destructuring properties of an object under a different variable name

```
const { value: question } = data;
```

creates a block-scoped constant named `question`, and assigns to it  `data.value`.

It's **identical** to

```
const question = data.value;
```